# Split file after n number of non consecutivempty lines

Tags: bash, shell, csplit

I am trying to split a big text files after n number of empty lines. The text file contains exactly one empty line as data separator. Like below:

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

Lorem
Lorem

...
```

I have tried to use csplit

```
csplit data.txt /^$/ {3}
```

My expectation is that after 3 empty lines (not consecutive, but after cursor processes 3 empty lines) it split file and continue to do so. But it actualy splits file in each empty line.

My expected files:
xx00

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum
```

xx01

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

Lorem
Lorem
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem you are having is a Regex applies to a LINE of data, not multiple lines. So the repetition `{3}` doesn't do what you want it to do. Another option is `awk` (or a bash script -- awk will be faster). In either case there you have the ability to use internal variables to keep count of the empty lines encountered.

Comment: _not consecutive, but after cursor processes 3 empty lines_ But is it possible that there are consecutive empty lines?

Comment: Also, the output you show is inconsistent with a split at the 3rd newline.  In that case `xx00` should not have the final 2 lines you show. `xx00` shows splitting the line on the 4th newline, which would remove the first two lines in `xx01`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin corrected the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` (tested with GNU and BSD `awk`):

```bash
awk -v max=3 '{print > sprintf("xx%02d", int(n/max))} /^$/ {n += 1}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should also work with an empty `RS`:

```bash
awk -v n=3 -v RS= '{ORS=RT; print > sprintf("xx%02d", int((NR-1)/n))}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk is good for this.

Split every `n` empty lines, naming files with:

No leading zeroes:

```
awk -v n=3 '
$0 == "" {++c}
c <= n {print > "xx"f}
c==n {c=0; ++f}'
```

`width` minimum width/zeroes:

```
awk -v n=3 -v width=2 '
$0 == "" {++c}
c <= n {print > "xx"f}
c==n {c=0; ++f; f = sprintf("%0*d",width,f)}'
```

To remove the trailing empty line in each file, just change `c <= n` to `c < n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
removed './xx00'
removed './xx01'
removed './awkprof.out'

    {m,g}awk '{
        print >> sprintf("xx%0*.f%.*s", __-(_~_),
                 int(_/__),_<_,_+=!NF) }' FS='^$' __=3

-rw-r--r--  1 501  75 Jun  8 09:19:10 2022 xx00
-rw-r--r--  1 501  37 Jun  8 09:19:10 2022 xx01


../../Desktop/testdiremptylines/

     1  Lorem ipsum
     2  Lorem ipsum
     3  Lorem ipsum
     4  
     5  Lorem ipsum
     6  Lorem ipsum
     7  
     8  Lorem ipsum
     9  

 xx00

     1  Lorem ipsum
     2  Lorem ipsum
     3  
     4  Lorem
     5  Lorem

 xx01
```